# Problemas al recuperar datos que contienen unicode en mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode

Estimados me pasaron un sitio en el que debo reparar la función de búsqueda y me tope con el siguiente problema:

Hay un columna en la bd, para este ejemplo 'name', la que almacena los datos de la siguiente forma: **{"es":"Balloon Puc\u00f3n y Curarrehue 2014"}**

Como pueden ver la palabra "Pucón" queda almacenada con el acento en la o en formato unicode (\u00f3) si no me equivoco. Debido a esto la query que pongo mas abajo no me devuelve nada

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name LIKE '%pucon%';
```

El sitio utiliza mysql, el campo es de tipo LONGTEXT, el charset es utf8 con Collation utf8_unicode_ci

De que forma podría recuperar los datos que contienen caracteres en unicode?

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar formateando el dato antes de exportarlo ejemplo:

cambio global:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

formatiando a utf8 en query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(name USING utf8) FROM projects name LIKE '%pucon%';
```

cambiado del todo en la configuracion my.ini:

```
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server= utf8mb4
```

cambiando desde php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

cambiando desde desde html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

cambiando antes desde tu app:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

recuerda siempre sanear para:

```
"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?"
bind_param("s", name );

"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE name = :name"
bind_param("s", name );
```